# Using OpenTouchMap on Android Environment

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I am using the free map service: 'http://www.opentouchmap.org/' to view various buildings in an establishment using a WebView object.

My question is, is there a GET-parameter or script I can use to create a border so that the user cannot E.g."Go to China and back"?

Here is my code so far:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //No need to worry about security
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.opentouchmap.org/?  lat=latitude&lon=longitude&zoom=15");



        //TODO: what to do here??
        webview.evaluateJavascript("",null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Anyone????????..........

Comment: If you use a third party service - either use the existing API or write a workaround (which could break if they change their API). And if you don't know how at least list out what you've searched for/tried.